About a point in a piecewise function
I would like to create a graph as shown below using Wolfram Mathematica:

This is what I've tried:
pw[x_] := Piecewise[{{x + 3, x < 1}, {(x - 2)^2, x >= 1}}]

Plot[pw[x], {x, -4.3, 6}, Epilog -> {PointSize@Medium, Point[{1, 1}]}]

What I've got of the graph is this:

I'm stuck. I don't know how to generate that small circle at the point (1,4).
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Additional Question:
Is there another way of creating the graph without using Epilog?

Can you live with this? Plot[pw[x],{x,-4.3,6},Epilog->{PointSize@Medium,Point[{1,1}], Circle[{1,4},{1/14,1/7}]}] Study the docs for Circle to learn all the things you can adjust to try to make it appear more like you have to have.

You could superimpose a white Point onto a black Point. Or you could find a special character (e.g. [EmptyCircle]) and use Text.

I am doing your suggestions right now. I will just feedback later

@Bill Yes, the circle is same as that of the size of the point at (1,1). My only problem is that the line overlap the circle, particularly, the endpoint of the line is at the center of the circle

@JunivenAcapulco I think I understand your problem. That was why I asked if you could live with my suggestion. I realize that many people think the exactly correct display of graphics and math notation is more important than anything. Long ago you used to pay people to do graphics for you. You might be able to use what @lericr suggested. Or you might be able to Plot from -4.3 to slightly less than 1 and a second Plot from 1 to 6 and then add my circle and combine all those using Show Hopefully you didn't waste too much time on my idea and I hope you find a solution that you can accept.

@Bill Thank you very much to all of your suggested comments. I was then motivated to really look at the solution on my own.

Exclusions and ExclusionsStyle could help; but I don't know how to draw the exclusion points in different styles on the left and right of the discontinuity. Something like Plot[pw[x], {x, -4.3, 6}, ExclusionsStyle -> {None, PointSize[0.02]}] but with two different point styles (how?).

pw = Piecewise[{{2, 1 <= x < 2}, {1, 2 <= x <= 3}}];
Show[Plot[pw, {x, 1, 3}],ListPlot[{{2, 2}}, PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers"], ListPlot[{{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}},PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, "Medium"}]]



After doing some readings on the web particularly in this site, I was able to come up with the codes that I needed to generate the required graph.
Here is the code:
pw[x_] := Piecewise[{{x + 3, x < 1}, {(x - 2)^2, x >= 1}}]

Plot[pw[x], {x, -4.3, 6}, PlotRange -> {-2.5, 10}, 
PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.004]},
AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
Epilog -> {{Disk[{1, 1}, 0.1]}, {White, EdgeForm[Black], Disk[{1, 4}, 0.1]}}]


